# Best Practices for CRUD/FLS/SHARING checks in unmanaged code

Tags: apex, security, bestpractice, pmd

I'm auditing an ORGS unmanaged Apex and trying to form a concrete framework for when I care about PMD warning for [`ApexCRUDViolation`](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexcrudviolation) & [`ApexSharingViolations`](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexsharingviolations).

It's always been my understanding that there are many valid use cases it's fine to run `SOQL/DML` without checking.  One example that covers both use cases:

> A Trigger that calculates a custom "rollup" value.  The calculation may need to query records the user doesn't have sharing or even object access to, and we don't want to allow the user to update the field manually.

On the other hand, if you have a UI that is displaying record data or performing DML from user input, you probably do want to check.

- Is my above understanding correct?
- Are there any other conditions I should take into consideration?
- Are there any other best practices around this? (maybe all warnings should be ["suppressed"](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) to indicate they are intentional by the dev)

Comment: Sorry if this is duplicate. 

I searched pretty hard on `stackexchange/reddit/google` and couldn't find anything that really dove into this from the unmanaged perspective.

Everything seems to be in reguards to passing the AppExchange Security review

Comment: IMHO the same rules should apply whether it is managed or unmanaged software. While you won't have Salesforce Security breathing down your neck about it, the reason to apply these policies is to ensure data stays safe and is only accessible and manageable by people (and through APIs) with the right permissions.

Comment: @PhilW before the updates that Mohith mentioned below (`insert as system`, etc), I would argue completely avoiding `ApexCRUDViolation` & `ApexSharingViolations` is security theater that actually would result in a less secure environment due to the required escalation of user privilege

Comment: I did not say you entirely avoid all warnings from PMD etc. Where your code needs to do something that bypasses "normal" security, you do so and mark it as a false positive. This is what you do in managed package code. I am saying the practices should be the same in unmanaged/subscriber/happy soup as well.

Comment: @PhilW Gotcha, I've never published to an AppExchange package, but the resources I was reading seemed to indicate the Salesforce Security Review was very strict around `ApexCRUDViolation` & `ApexSharingViolations`. 

They all just talk about HOW to enforce security controls with very little guidance around WHEN to enforce (or when it's acceptable not to).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my recommendations based on my experience working on the unmanaged code

- **Secure By Default Principle** - Run any apex code in the user mode unless you need to explicitly run in System mode. A good example as you know is a trigger scenario or a batch process or a queueable job.
- We added the [user mode database operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/05/write-simplified-and-secure-apex-with-spring-23-updates) where you can explicitly specify that you want to run something in System mode like `insert as system`. Write comments as to why your code needs to run in System mode.

Comment: Thanks! `insert as system` sounds like a great addition to be able to run in user mode but explicit drop into system mode as needed.

Comment: User mode is currently unusable in general terms on its own (it does not support the idea of certain fields for which the user must have permissions and others that are optional). This is awkward for "unmanaged" code and even more so for managed. The principle of permission escalation using a perm set that is coming may help, but I am still unconvinced and am concerned this could result in an explosion of perm sets designed to support specific use cases within the code base.